# Efficiently editing commands with zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

Let's say I use CTRL-R and then type tail to find the last time I ran tail.

What comes up is tail -F /path/to/log/file-2011-03-07.log

The command I want to run is the above command, but with 2011-03-08 instead of 2011-03-07. Is there a way to do replace with a regexp via the command line?

Answer (score 3):

`r 7=8 tail` should do it.  Read up on `fc` and `r`; they're not very widely known but very useful for this kind of thing.

There isn't regexp editing directly, but if you use `fc` directly you may be able to play with `fc -e` a bit.  (Indeed, `fc -e 'sed -ie s/foo/bar/' command` appears to work.  You might be able to wrap that in a function.)  There's also `-m` to use a shell glob to select the command from history.

Comment: Your answer directed me zshexpn(1) where I was able to find out that I could do something like this:

!tail:s/6/7

Which kind of does what I want. Will take a look at r, fc and zshexpn(1) more to see what is possible!